# How to mount Touch phone as external drive on MacOS

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I have a Nexus 4 running Touch OTA-14. When I plug it into my MacBook USB it shows up in the list of devices, but it does not mount as a drive on the desktop. I've looked through settings and developer options and do not see anything to configure this. Is it possible? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to mount it if it makes a device node in /dev. Just watch for disk0s9, where 9 will be the partition #, to appear in /dev after you plug the device in. Then run 'mkdir /mnt/disk -p && sudo mount /dev/disk0s9 /mnt/disk' to make a folder to mount the disk to, and to mount the disk!

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. It shows up in the list of USB devices in System Information. It doesn't show up in /dev/disk* nor does plugging it in show any activity in system.log.